# Sum and Direct Sum of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm given that: $$A := \{(\alpha,\alpha,\alpha) :\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ and $$B := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x+y+z=0\}.$$

I'm trying to determine the following:

- None of the answers are correct
- $A + B = \mathbb R^3$
- $A \oplus B = \mathbb R^3$
- $A + B = A ⊕ B$
- $A ⊕ B \neq \mathbb R^3$
- $A ⊕ B \neq \mathbb R^2$
- $A ⊕ B \neq \mathbb R$

I think $A + B = A ⊕ B$ since $A \cap B = \{0\}$. How do I prove/disprove the rest?

Comment: Please do not rely on images to convey information that is not in the post. See [here for an explanation why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, I added Q5

Comment: Great; so in order to answer my comment saying you should *not* use images, you decided to *add another image*. Why direct your comment at me, if you are just ignoring what I wrote?

Comment: Sorry. I removed images and added the text

Comment: [Here is a MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks to you for the link & the few helpful who also helped suggest edits. I'm looking forward to discussing the question at hand and learn

Comment: Geometrically, $A$ is a line through the origin and $B$ is the plane through the origin normal to that line. If you understand this, then the question should essentially answer itself.

Comment: Since options 2 and 4 are negations of each other, it is clear that "None of the answer are correct" cannot possibly be right.

Comment: Yes, since I feel like +=⊕, then I understand it cannot be none of the options. @AlexProvost I'm not entirely sure what that means, I understand that you're saying that B is a plane through the origin that is perpendicular (normal?) to the line A. I think the key is that if I figure what ⊕  is equal to (R, R^2, R^3, etc), then I know if A+B = R^3 since +=⊕

Comment: @sekib72409 By definition $A+B \subseteq \mathbb R^3$; it should be obvious why $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are nonsensical answers. Now ask yourself whether $A+B$ is indeed the whole of $\mathbb R^3$; in other words, are there vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ that *aren't* a combination of a vector in the plane and a vector in the line?

Comment: I think that there are such vectors? Like the vector (1,2,3) $\neq$ 0

Comment: Well that's certainly not convincing: $(1,2,3) = (2,2,2) + (-1,0,1)$; the former is in $A$ while the latter is in $B$.